# How do I open an Audacity on RPI startup?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, audacity

I am trying to use python to open Audacity (audio recording software) on startup. So far, I've tried `subprocess.call` and `subprocess.run`. `subprocess.run` worked, but when I tried to run it at start up it didn't work.

I tried the following:

```
import subprocess

#this first method didn't work
subprocess.call(('xdg-open', 'path_to_audacity.desktop'))

#this is the second method it worked, it just didn't work on start up
subprocess.run("audacity",shell=True)
```

Does anyone know any way of opening Audacity on start up with Python?